# Java | Shift out of bounds index until it is in bounds

Tags: java

Let's say that I have an array x.

```
char[] x = new char[10]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
```

I want to access the array with an index that is out of bounds. 
For example:

### index --> value

-2 --> i
-1 --> j
0 --> a
1 --> b
9 --> j
10 --> a
11 --> b
16 --> g
19 --> j
20 --> a

Comment: `char` is `unsigned` so you can't assign a negative number to it, n AFAIK negative index is not allowed in Java language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the modulus operator, e.g.:

```
int index = 20;
int position = ((index % x.length) + 10) % x.length;
char val = x[position];
```

I don't know why you think you need to use loops here, or if that be some requirement you have.  Using `%` is probably the easiest way to do this.

If you needed to use loops, the following comes to mind:

```
int i = 0;
int index = 20;
while (index > 0) {
    i++;
    if (i == x.length) i = 0;
    --index;
}
char val = x[i];
```

That is, we can spin over the bounds of the array based on the given input index (which may exceed the bounds of the array).  When we hit the end, we reset the running index to the start again.

Comment: LOL *How can I achieve this with for loops?* do you think he really wants to use loops?

Comment: What about for negative numbers? I should have specified, let me update the question.

Comment: You didn't use `for` loop :) Your code will be simpler with it.

Comment: @Provision I edited my question to cover the negative index case.